# TypeError: javaScriptConfirm() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given) python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebview

```
self.browser = QWebView()
self.page = MyWebPage()
self.browser.setPage(self.page)
```

the MyWebPage() class is:

```
class MyWebPage(QWebPage):
    def javaScriptAlert(self):
        pass
    def javaScriptConfirm(self):
        pass
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self):
        pass
    def javaScriptPrompt(self):
        pass
```

then I get the type error:

> TypeError: javaScriptConfirm() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

can anyone tell me why I am getting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to overwrite some method of a class the function must have the same number of arguments, if we review the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html):

> **virtual void    javaScriptAlert(QWebFrame * frame, const QString & msg)**
>
> **virtual bool    javaScriptConfirm(QWebFrame * frame, const QString & msg)**
>
> **virtual void    javaScriptConsoleMessage(const QString & message, int
>    lineNumber, const QString & sourceID)**
>
> **virtual bool    javaScriptPrompt(QWebFrame * frame, const QString & msg, const QString & defaultValue, QString * result)**

by reviewing you must overwrite the methods as follows:

```
class MyWebPage(QWebPage):
    def javaScriptAlert(self, frame, msg):
        pass
    def javaScriptConfirm(self, frame, msg):
        pass
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, message, lineNumber, sourceID):
        pass
    def javaScriptPrompt(self, frame, msg, defaultValue, result):
        pass
```

Or if you are not going to use any of those parameters you could use `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
class MyWebPage(QWebPage):
    def javaScriptAlert(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def javaScriptConfirm(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def javaScriptPrompt(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Comment: When I run the code I get another type error that there is an invalid result from MyWebPage.javaScriptConfirm() and I then changed pass to True but I still get the samd error, would you know how to fix this?